# On Windows how to get network interface name whether its eth0/eth1/eth2 using batch script?

Tags: windows, batch-file, networking, interface

I am working on windows and wanted to get the network interface name whether its eth0, eth1, eth2 etc etc etc. I wrote java program and by passing host/computer name I can find out ip address and thereafter based on an ip address I can find out network interface name. The code is as below:

```
public static String getNetworkInterface() {
        try {
            String computerHostName = "dummy";
            if(!computerHostName.equals("Unknown Computer")) {
                InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(computerHostName); 
                return NetworkInterface.getByInetAddress(address).getName();
            }
            else {
                return null;
            }
        }
        catch (SocketException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

The above method returns the value something like eth0/eth1/eth2 etc.

Same thing I want to achieve using batch script on windows. I wrote following script which is providing hostname and an ip address. But I don't know as to how to get the network interface name.

```
for /f "skip=1 delims=" %%A in (
  'wmic computersystem get name'
) do for /f "delims=" %%B in ("%%A") do set "compName=%%A"

echo hostname is %compName%
```

This scripts gives hostname/computername.

Please help me to get network interface name.

Thanks a lot. 
regards,
Yeshwant

Comment: try, `for /f "tokens=2-5 delims=," %%a in ('wmic nic where "netconnectionid like '%%'" get MACAddress^,AdapterType^,NetConnectionId^,Name /format:csv') do (
      echo %%a, %%b, %%c, %%d
    )`

Comment: Hi elzooilogico, I tried your suggestion. Can you point out any mistake if any, which you see: for /f "tokens=2-5 delims=," %%a in ('wmic nic where "netconnectionid like '%%'" get MACAddress^,AdapterType^,NetConnectionId^,Name /format:csv') do ( echo %%a, %%b, 

%%c, %%d ) Error I am getting : C:\Users\user>testnew.bat

C:\Users\user>for /F "tokens=2-5 delims=," %a in ('wmic nic where "netconnectionid like '%'" get MACAddress,AdapterType,NetConnectionId,Name /format:csv') do (echo %a, %b, %c, %d  )
No Instance(s) Available.
Invalid XSL format (or) file name.

C:\Users\user>

Comment: I specified full path of format: for /f "tokens=2-5 delims=," %%a in ('wmic nic where "netconnectionid like '%%'" get MACAddress^,AdapterType^,NetConnectionId^,Name /format:"%WINDIR%\System32\wbem

\en-US\csv"') do ( echo %%a, %%b, %%c, %%d )
Result is: C:\Users\user>testtemp.bat

C:\Users\user>for /F "tokens=2-5 delims=," %a in ('wmic nic where "netconnectionid like '%'" get MACAddress,AdapterType,NetConnectionId,Name /format:"C:\Windows\System32\wbem\en-US\csv"') do (echo %a, %b, %c, %d  )
No Instance(s) Available.

, , ,   ) ser>(echo
, , ,

Comment: @yeswant, try this in commandline `for /f "tokens=2-5 delims=," %a in ('wmic nic where "netconnectionid like '%%'" get MACAddress^,AdapterType^,NetConnectionId^,Name /format:csv') do echo %a, %b, %c, %d`. If you were to put on a batch file you must  write any `%` as `%%`, so `echo %a, %b, ...` will be `echo %%a, %%b, ...`

Comment: Thanks Elzoologico: I tried from the command line and here is the result. Any idea what is no instances available means: C:\Users\user>for /f "tokens=2-5 delims=," %a in ('wmic nic where "netconnectionid like '%%'" get MACAddress^,AdapterType^,NetConnectionId^,Name /format:csv') do echo %a, %b, %c, %d
No Instance(s) Available.

, , ,  s\user>echo
, , ,

C:\Users\user>

Comment: @yeswant, you don't have network connection or its status is unknow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should give you the Network Interface Name:

```bat
@Echo Off
For /F "Skip=1Delims=" %%a In (
    '"WMIC NIC Where (Not NetConnectionStatus Is Null) Get NetConnectionID"'
) Do For /F "Tokens=*" %%b In ("%%a") Do Echo=%%b
Timeout -1
```

Comment: Compo: this is giving me the result as below:C:\Users\user>testtemp1.bat
No Instance(s) Available.

Press any key to continue ...

C:\Users\user>

Comment: That means exactly what it shows, you do not have a network connection returning a status of between 0–65535. _What it doesn't mean is that there is something wrong with my code._

Comment: This only printed all connected interfaces for me ... didn't he ask for the interface given an IP-address?

Comment: Besides not specifically asking for that, my last response doesn't really alter that, if there is no network connection then I'd wager that it wouldn't have an IP Address

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find the network interface based on a IP-address you can use:

```
@echo off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set ownIP=W.X.Y.Z
set netifc=
FOR /F "tokens=4*" %%G IN ('netsh interface ipv4 show interfaces ^| findstr /I "[^a-zA-Z]connected"') DO (
    REM set /P =interface %%G is connected < nul >> !progress!
    netsh interface ipv4 show addresses "%%H" | findstr /c "%ownIP%" > nul 2>&1
    IF !ERRORLEVEL! EQU 0 (
        set netifc=%%H
    )
)

:outLoop
echo IP-address %ownIP% from interface %netifc%
EndLocal
exit /b 0
```

I use `netsh` instead of `WMIC` because I don't have much experience in `WMIC` but `netsh` is sufficient in your case.
Note that the `SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion` is very important as this script is based on checking the `ERRORLEVEL`. The cmd-parser parses every block of commands delimited with `()` as being one single command as if it was written on one line (in our case `FOR ... ( ... )` ). It is thus impossible to use a changing variable with its updated value inside a `()` unless you use delayed expansion. If you don't, only the value before entering the block can be used. As `ERRORLEVEL` can change in each iteration (will be 0 if the IP-address has been found by the `findstr` above it in the addresses of an interface or 1 if it hasn't), we always need the updated value. This is also why I use `!ERRORLEVEL!` instead of the classic `%ERRORLEVEL%`.
More info about `EnableDelayedExtension` can be found [here](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html).

Running the script above with `set ownIP=127.0.0.1` (don't forget to change to your IP) gives the following result:

```
>search_interface.bat
IP-address 127.0.0.1 from interface Loopback Pseudo-Interface 1
```

If you'd like to pass the IP-address as an argument each time you call the script, use `set ownIP=%~1` (but don't forget to add a check if an argument has been passed in that case).

Hope it helps.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you J. Baoby. I first provided IP address of my PC and then the 127.0.0.1. Results are as below: C:\Users\user>notepad testtemp1.bat

C:\Users\user>testtemp1.bat
IP-address 192.168.1.152 from interface Local Area Connection

C:\Users\user>testtemp1.bat
IP-address 127.0.0.1 from interface Loopback Pseudo-Interface 1

C:\Users\user> Its not giving me what I want. How come through java program I am getting eth4 but batch script giving me value "Local Area Network"/"Loopback Pseudo-Interface 1". ?

Comment: In the [NetworkInterface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/NetworkInterface.html)-class, there are 2 methods that people often confuse with each other: [getDisplayName](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/NetworkInterface.html#getDisplayName--) and [getName](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/NetworkInterface.html#getName--). Those are 2 different methods and have different workings: the first gives a description of the device provided by the OS (in our case Windows) the latter is an interfacename Java makes himself to make it more portable

Comment: Here is [a little tuto](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/nifs/listing.html) where they demonstrate the two of them. Note that in some OS's (I think mainly Unix-like OS's) the 2 may give the same result but that is obviously not the case in Windows. As the first one is coming from Windows in our case, it is Windows itself that decides which names he'll pass to Java. I've done a look-up in the register entries. I looked up the names provided by `netsh` and `wmic` and saw they were in a complete different register directory than the descriptive names Windows gave to Java.

Comment: You can do the search you too, just open `regedit` (via the Run panel for eg.) and search (`Ctrl+F`) for the display names provided by Java and those by `netsh`. I did the search based on [this site](http://www.kapilarya.com/how-to-rename-devices-in-device-manager-using-registry) (I just left out the "rename"-part though :p)

Comment: It's my pleasure. Hope it helps. The real reason why Windows decides to "hide" some of the real devices is still kind of a mystery to me too. Maybe for security reasons...I'll definitely let you know if I find something more about it

Comment: Ok sure. Thanks in advance. If you find some solution do let me know. I am yet to try out the solution you provided as I am occupied with work. Thanks Baoby. See you around.